# How to push different data to each observer upon external event?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have service that acts as data storage (simple associative array). There are multiple components that are interested in this data - each of them wants values under one or more keys, but they never want entire thing. Storage service also listens for external event and reacts to it by recalculating all values in array. I am trying to implement the whole thing using rxjs Observables.

I read that Observables execute their subsicribe() function separately for each observer. This sounds exactly like what I need, but I cannot figure out:

1. How should observer tell Observable during subscription that it is interested only in selected items?
2. How do I update all observers when data is recalculated (external event happen)? In example below I use `next()` on Subject, but this would send the same data through all Observables.

Below is simplified version of what I have now:

> storage.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {
    externalEvent = Observable.interval(2500);
    data = {};

    output = new Subject();

    constructor() { 
        this.externalEvent.subscribe(n => {
            this.data = {"a": Math.random(), "b": Math.random(), "c": Math.random()};
            this.output.next(this.data);
        });
    }

}
```

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { StorageService } from './storage.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template: `
    <app-child [param]="'a'"></app-child>
    <app-child [param]="'b'"></app-child>
`,
providers: [StorageService]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

> child.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { StorageService } from './storage.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-child',
template: `
    <p>{{ data }}</p>
`
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() param: string;
    data: string;

    constructor(private storage: StorageService) {
        this.storage.output.subscribe(d => {
            console.log(`child ${this.param} received ${JSON.stringify(d)}`);
            this.data = d[this.param];
        });
    }
    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly you could turn `output` into a method that accepts the "key" you want to observe.

```
output(key: string): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.of(this.data[key])
    .merge(this.output.map(newData => newData[key]))
    .filter(Boolean) // Emit only when there's any data?
}
```

This way when you call `this.output.next()` with new data (even if it'll contain for example only keys that have changed) it'll notify all observers with new data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a data of a service i will do like this:

> storage.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {
    externalEvent = Observable.interval(2500);
    data = {};

     private _outputEvent$: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

    constructor() { 
        this.externalEvent.subscribe(n => {
            this.data = {"a": Math.random(), "b": Math.random(), "c": Math.random()};
            this.setOutputEvent(this.data);
        });
    }

   /**
   * Transform OutputEvent subject to an observable.
   */
  getOutputEvent() {
    return this._outputEvent$.asObservable();
  }

  /**
   * Sends data through OutputEvent subject.
   * @param value data to output.
   */
  setOutputEvent(value: any) {
    this._outputEvent$.next(value);
  }

}
```

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { StorageService } from './storage.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template: `
    <app-child [param]="'a'"></app-child>
    <app-child [param]="'b'"></app-child>
`,
providers: [StorageService]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

> child.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { StorageService } from './storage.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-child',
template: `
    <p>{{ data }}</p>
`
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() param: string;
    data: string;

    constructor(private storage: StorageService) {
        this.storage.getOutputEvent().subscribe(
            response => {
               console.log(`child ${this.param} received ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
               // this.data = response[this.param];
               this.data = response.param;
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    }
    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```